# Wpf/WinRT points to draw a heart

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, math, winrt-xaml

I've been drawing various shapes on a canvas and I have managed to figure out the math to do things like hexagons, octagons, and even stars.  I can't seem to figure out how to draw a heart.  Does anyone have an example of the points needed to draw a heart shape?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a really easy way to plot equations straight on to the `Canvas` (although you could certainly create the `Path` from an equation programmatically. .depending on what you want to do with the shape, and where you want to use it, you could just define a `Path` using the [Path Markup Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx) and use some of the built in arcs and curves.

e.g. (quickly threw this one together):

```
<Canvas>
    <Path Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="3" 
        Data="M 241,200 
              A 20,20 0 0 0 200,240
              C 210,250 240,270 240,270
              C 240,270 260,260 280,240
              A 20,20 0 0 0 239,200
              " />
</Canvas>
```

Will create something that looks like this:
[image]

Which uses 2 arcs and 2 cubic Bezier curves.

You can read more about the syntax link, but by way of a small explanation (the following draws half the heart, from the dip at the top of the heart to the point at the bottom, counter-clockwise):

```
M 241,200             // Move to (241, 200)
A 20,20 0 0 0 200,240 // Draw an arc from current position to (200,240), with a size of 20x20 pixels
C 210,250 240,270 240,270 // Draw a cubic Bezier to point (240,270) with control points at (210,250), (240,270).
```

The next curve, then arc are drawn, arriving back at the top, completing the shape.

You may have to play around a bit to get the result you're after.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of mathematical equations for heart shapes - some polar, some parametric.

One particularly convincing one is:

```
x = 16sin^3(t)
y = 13cos(t) - 5cos(2t) - 2cos(3t) - cos(4t)
```

There's a list of some good ones [on the Woflram website](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeartCurve.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can plot a heart on a graph with the following equation.

((x^2 + y^2 - 1)^3) - (x^2 * y^3) = 0

[image]

Source : [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_%28symbol%29)

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, you can draw two arcs as parts of two upper intersecting circles that have the center on the same X axis; and then two lower lines to unite them. I tried to draw an example, I hope the picture is suggestive enough:[image: drawing a heart]